# Is there a way to get pywin32 to use vcvars32.bat instead of vcvarsall.bat?

Tags: python, pywin32

So, I'm just trying to build pywin32 on my Windows 7 machine. When running the setup script, I ran into the common error of "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat". I do have Visual C++ installed, so I was somewhat confused. After a bit of searching around, here as well as other sites, I found that the best solution to my problem would probably be to add the path to the batch file right to my path. However, when looking for that path, I realized that, since I have Visual Studio 2010 installed rather than 2008 or earlier, I have a file called "vcvars32.bat" instead of the usual "vavarsall.bat".

Is it possible to get the setup script to use vcvars32? This is probably ridiculous and may reveal how little I know about batch files, but could I perhaps copy and rename the vcvars32.bat file to vcvarsall.bat, or are they too fundamentally different to work properly?

Or do I just need to install an older version of Visual Studio? I would really rather not if I could avoid it. I have also been having trouble building with MinGW. Are there any files I need to download first?

Thanks in advance,

Ken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to get pywin32 to use vcvars32.bat instead of
>   vcvarsall.bat?

There's no need.

> I realized that, since I have Visual Studio 2010 installed rather than
>   2008 or earlier, I have a file called "vcvars32.bat" instead of the
>   usual "vcvarsall.bat".

You have both and `vcvars32.bat` is being used by `vcvarsall.bat`. For instance, on the 64 bit Windows typical installation paths for these files in Visual Studio 2010 are

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat`

> Or do I just need to install an older version of Visual Studio?

If you use official Python builds then you have to install an older version - Visual Studio 2008 or 2005 depending on what version of Python you use. That's because these versions of Visual Studio are used to make official Python builds and you have to use the same version of compiler when building C extension modules.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a `vcvarsall.bat` which simply

```
"%~dp0\vcvars32.bat"
```

runs the `vcvars32.bat` in the same folder.

(I think.  I haven't touched Windows in what feels like years… happily ☺)

Comment: wouldn't this accomplish the same thing as making a copy of the file and renaming it?

Comment: @KenB: Sure, but this way updating the original file doesn't require updating the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the binary version of pywin32 is much simpler and doesn't require the installation of any c++ compilers. For some reason it isn't easy to find these on the sourceforge website, but it is definitely there. Here is the link to all of the executables for version 2.14: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20214/